# Piping RxJS BehaviorSubject and assigning again to BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my Angular application I have implemented a loading indicator that I can control via an Angular service by setting a `BehaviorSubject` I called `isBusy$`.
Now I want to set a delay on the `BehaviorSubject`, so that changes to `isBusy$` are only triggers after 500ms.

After reading https://ckjaersig.dk/2020/05/showing-a-loading-spinner-delayed-with-rxjs/ I have come up with the following approach:

```
  private isBusy$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private debouncedIsBusy$: Observable<boolean> = this.isBusy$.pipe(debounceTime(500));
```

With that I can pass `debouncedIsBusy$` to Angular's async pipe and it does the job just fine.

While I was experimenting I also tried the following which also seemed to work:

```
  private isBusy$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500)
    ) as BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
```

In this case a new `BehaviorSubject` is created then immediately piped which returns a (new?) `Observable`.
Then it is assigned to `isBusy$` with the help of `as`.

I was surprised that this worked as I did not expect the `Observable` returned by `pipe` to be an `BehaviorSubject`.
Is this correct code? And if so is it good practice?

Best regards!

Comment: Yes, the assign is correct because  BehaviorSubject extends Subject and Subject extends Observable.

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice to do that. The type returned by the `.pipe` method is an `Observable`. Now this works for you because various reasons, but nobody can guarantee to you that in the next versions of rxjs this will keep working. The contract between you and `pipe` is that you get back an `Observable`, not a `BehaviorSubject` or whatever the source of that Observable is.

Comment: Your first approach is good though, that's the way to go. You can also make the `debouncedIsBusy$` observable public, and use it directly. Because it's an Observable, you cannot `.next` from the outside of your service and your loading logic remains confined within that service.

Comment: Agree with @OctavianMărculescu comment. Also it's not clear why you might need `debounceTime(500)` there. I can imagine using `distinctUntilChanged()` in a pipe so that consumers get updates only when value changed. And you can emit to subject as often as you want to